# How can I reuse Vue and Vuetify code?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

```js
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      my_alert: false,
      text: '',
      color: 'success'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openAlt (text, color) {
      this.text = text
      this.color = color
      this.my_alert = true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn @click="openAlt('This is alert', 'error')">Click me!</v-btn>
      <v-snackbar v-model="my_alert"
            :timeout="2000"
            :color="color"
            top right>
      {{ text }}
      <v-btn icon ripple @click="my_alert = false">
        <v-icon>close</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-snackbar>
  </div>
</template>
```

I'm studying Vue.js and Vuetify. I wrote a code that shows alert after click on v-btn.

How can I reuse this alert outside of this page?

I want to modularise this code and use it for alerts for all of my pages.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think creating a mixin works as well:

Say that you create alertMixin.js as below:

```
const alertMixin = {
  data () {
    return {
      myAlert: false,
      text: '',
      color: 'success',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openAlt (text, color) {
      this.text = text;
      this.color = color;
      this.myAlert = true;
    }
  }
};

export default alertMixin;
```

And use it where ever you want like this:

```
<script>
import alertMixin from '@/path/to/mixin/alertMixin';

export default {
  name: 'where-ever-you-want',
  mixins: [alertMixin],
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi welcome to vuetiful world of vue.

You can easily do that making the alert as an component and importing it where ever you want.

For any file where you want to use your alert code, you could just import your alert component and use it just like any other HTML component.

```
import alert from './path/to/component

<template>
    <appAlert></appAlert>
</template>

<script>
 components:{
     appAlert: alert
}
</script>
```

There more you can do with components, Read about [Vue components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thx for your answer(and edited my english :D). Now, I can import components in my pages. but, what I want to is that calling openAlt method in the compoment from other pages and showing alert(so I'm going to remove v-btn from the template). Can I do it? Thx.

Comment: yes use $ref, to reference you component, you can then pass your methods among components and use your openAlt method.

Comment: Thx. Now I can import components in my pages and call component's method by using $refs(and it works well). If I want to use the component in all of my pages, can I import it App.vue? I tried it, but doesn't work(Vue.prototype.$app = App in main.js and called this.$app.openalt(x,y) in pages).

Comment: Yes there is a way for that too, Just define that component as global component, inside the main vue instance (most probably inside main.js). Then you don't even have to import that component all time, it will always be there.

Comment: Thank you very much. it works well. But, I think I'll have to use $EventBus to open alert(not $refs), is there anything else more better?

Comment: Inorder to implement Eventbus you need a separate and dedicated vue instance, which will be completely exclusive from the main vue instance. The only way of communication would be emits(events). So may be you should try emitting events and passing the alert function all along with it as a callback. This way is doable but definitely not recommended. I am actually more interested in knowing your code design. Sometimes hard problems have simple solutions.

Comment: Thank you. I posted my new code. It works well, but I think this is complex.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my new code.

App.vue

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <router-view/>
    </v-content>
    <alt></alt>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

main.js

```html
// ...
import alt from './components/alt'

Vue.prototype.$EventBus = new Vue()
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.component('alt', alt)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

alt.vue

```js
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      my_alert: false,
      text: '',
      color: 'success'
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.$EventBus.$on('show_alt', (str, color) => {
      var text = str
      var clr = color

      if (!text) text = '설정되지 않은 문구'
      if (!clr) clr = 'error'

      this.text = text
      this.color = clr
      this.my_alert = true
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
      <v-snackbar v-model="my_alert"
            :timeout="2000"
            :color="color"
            top right>
      {{ text }}
      <v-btn icon ripple @click="my_alert = false">
        <v-icon>close</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-snackbar>
  </div>
</template>
```

At last, altTest.vue

```html
<template>
  <v-btn @click="openAlt('This is alert', 'error')">Click Me!</v-btn>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {

    }
  },
  methods: {
    openAlt (str, color) {
      return this.$EventBus.$emit('show_alt', str, color)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I imported alt.vue to main.js as global, and it's added App.vue.

So, I can open alert in altTest.vue without import(but, it need a method openAlt()).

But, I think this is not simple..